# Decoding Solidity Return Type uint256 using Python web3.py drivers

Tags: solidity, web3.py

My solidity contract is got a function that returns a `uint256` type.

I would like to capture its value on my python web3 client. How can I do that on Python using web3 drivers? Do I need any other additional dependency to decode `unit256` byte array?

```
function getUserTotalBorrow(address user)
         public
         view
         returns (uint256 totalInDai)
    {
        uint256 len = supportedTokensList.length;
        for (uint256 i; i < len; ) {
            address token = supportedTokensList[i];

            uint256 tokenAmount = vaults[token].totalBorrow.toAmount(
                userBorrowBalance[user][token],
                false
            );
            if (tokenAmount != 0) {
                totalInDai += getTokenPrice(token) * tokenAmount;
            }

            unchecked {
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
```

My client looks as follows

In general, I'd like to check the value on my client of any function returning

Answer (score 1):

> web3 drivers

Python has [web3.py library](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py) for interacting with Solidity smart contracts.

- Compile your smart contracts
- [Set up a node to read on-chain data](https://ethereumnnodes.com) or use the built-in unit testing environment
- Import your ABI JSON file to Python
- Call your smart contract using [web3.py Contract objects](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.contract.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra dependency to decode an `uint256`.

Using `web3py` you can do it like this:

```
from web3 import Web3

# get abi
abi = contract_interface['abi']

# web3.py instance
w3 = Web3(Web3.EthereumProvider())

contract = w3.eth.contract(
    address=contractAddress,
    abi=abi
)

totalBorrow = contract.functions.getUserTotalBorrow(userAddress).call()
```

After doing this, you will have the return of the function stored in `totalBorrow` variable and you can just treat it as a normal `int`.

For more information on how to use these functions and the `web3py` library you can refer to [this link](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.contract.html).